# Keep the previous userform open after Unload.Me using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the `Unload.Me` function to close a userform.

I have two userforms, when I close one, the second userform will close automatically as well.

I want try to keep the previous userform open.

Comment: That should not happen. Where do you put `Unload Me`? And when you say the 2nd userform will close together, do you mean before that both are open?

Comment: Starting the userform1 show the userform2 by pressing the button ( userform2.show ). When i close the userform2,the userform1 will automatic close also. How can i just close the userform2 only but remain the userform1 open?

Comment: Where have you put `Unload me` ?

Comment: I put Unload.ME at userform2

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround, try to specify the exact form you are unloading.

i.e. use `Unload UserForm2`

If that doesn't help, check if the forms are modal forms. If not, set them to modal.

Comment: I try the Unload UserForm2 in my userform2. It still close together with the Userform1.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter on my machine, I would like to ask are both forms modal?

Comment: I Set both of the userform's Show Modal to True. Problem Solve.

Comment: Glad that you've solved the problem. I can't simulate the problem in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a subsequent instruction in the same sub procedure that called/showed Userform2 (thinking that it might not close Userform1 until it finished the rest of the code after Userform2.show).  Instructions like assigning a random value to a random variable did not work, but making a message box pop up did work.  For example in the sub procedure calling userform2 you might try:

> Userform2.show
>
> Msgbox("Userform2 has already closed.  Close this message box to see Userform1.")

This seems despotic to me too, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This's caused by a code that executes when the form that you don't want to close becomes the active form.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 now, but anyway, for those interested.
You do not need a messagebox, you can just set focus to an item in userform1.
That way you avoid having to click OK to close the messagebox

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's clear that the answer is unclear if you did not read the question and the offered solution.
The post answered Mar 9, 2016 at 4:39 the solution offered was 

Userform2.show
Msgbox("Userform2 has already closed. Close this message box to see Userform1.")

My answer was to replace the MsgBox ...  with setting focus to an object in UserForm1